# How to find top terms with occurrences in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, querydsl, elastic-stack

I have a fairly big dataset in Elasticsearch: 1 index, about 120 million records of one type. I am processing a large number of paragraphs on a given set of topics. The number of topics is limited and associated with a unique ID. Each paragraph has a couple of sentences identified by the `sentence_id` (unique across all topics). Each sentence has a number of words and each word can occur multiple times. So my `mapping` looks like the following:

```
{ 
    "sentence_id": 1200,
    "topic_id": 2,
    "value": "ground",
    "occurrences": 20
}
```

Now, I want to run a query which answers this:
"Find the top words for a given topic ID sorted by their occurrences."

So for each word in a topic, I have to `sum up` its occurrences across all the sentences, `sort` them and return.

I am not able to achieve this. I tried writing `aggregation term query`, but it does not sum occurrences and merely returns the unique count of records for each word.

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "topic_id": {
              "value": 3117
           }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "total_occurrences": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "occurrences",
                "size": 1000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can some one help me out?

Answer (score 2):

I think first you need to `aggregate` on unique `value`, and then [`sum`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) its `occurrences`, your query should look something like this assuming your `occurrences` field is `numeric`

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "topic_id": {
        "value": 3117
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "total_occurrences": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "value",
        "size": 1000,
        "order": {
          "sum_occurrences": "desc" <--- to sort by top words
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_occurrences": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "occurrences"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Hope this helps!